# Can't make texture transparent

Tags: c, opengl

I draw two textures, first Texture A and then Texture B. I always appears that A is always above b and even if some part of texture A is completely transparent, it just display the background color of screen. The background color here means the color i set with `glClearColor`. And however i change my code and picture, the transparent part of texture always has the same color of background color.

Here is my shader language source code.

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler; 
varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, v_TexCoord);
}
```

And i have already enabled blending function.

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you rendering this with 2 draw calls or are you using multi-texture.  If you are doing it as 2 draw calls then turn off the depth-test as the second texture will always fail the depth test (as its not in front of the polygon in the same place as it) and hence won't get drawn.

If you are using multi-texture then your problem probably lies with how you are setting up alpha.

I really suspect it the former though.

Comment: You could also switch the depth func from GL_LESS to GL_LEQUAL. However switching to multitexturing looks like a better solution than that.

Comment: Why can't i up vote for twice. This is the answer. I have think about it for two days and quite frustrate with it. Can you give me some advices on it to prevent this happen again. (I have read the document quite a log).

Comment: Kos's idea is one but you have to use EXACTLY the same vertices for both draw calls as otherwise floating point rounding errors will hurt you.  Generally using multi-texturing is the best plan though. See here for a tutorial: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bump-mapping,_multi-texturing_&_extensions/16009/